# Média individual não retorna valor e a quantidade das situações de alunos não contabilizam em C#

Tags: c#

Meu código ele recebe 3 notas de alunos e que mostre sua média, contabiliza a quantidade de aprovados, reprovados e que ainda estão em exames e mostrar a média de todos.

**O problemas do meu código são a contabilização da situações dos alunos que não estão de acordo com as notas que são digitadas e mostrar a média individual de cada aluno que também não estão de acordo.**

```
using System;

namespace TesteRepeticao1
{
    class Program8
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var alunos = new int[3];
            int i, reprovados = 0, exame = 0, aprovados = 0;
            double nota1 = 0, nota2 = 0, nota3 = 0, media = 0, mediaclasse = 0, somamedias = 0;
            for (i = 0; i <= alunos.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Digite a primeira nota do aluno {i}: ");
                nota1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite a segunda nota do aluno {i}: ");
                nota2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite a terceira nota do aluno {i}: ");
                nota3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                media = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3;
                somamedias += media;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            for (i = 0; i < alunos.Length; i++)
            {
                if(media < 5)
                {
                    reprovados++;
                }
                else if (media >= 5 && media < 7)
                {
                    exame++;
                }
                else if (media >= 7 && media < 10)
                {
                    aprovados++;
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < alunos.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"A média do aluno {alunos[i]} é {media}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            mediaclasse = somamedias / 3;
            Console.WriteLine($"O total de alunos reprovados é {reprovados}");
            Console.WriteLine($"O total de alunos em exame é {exame}");
            Console.WriteLine($"O total de alunos aprovados é {aprovados}");
            Console.WriteLine($"A média da classe é {mediaclasse}");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem dois erros e um bug com seu código.

Erros:

- Na linha `for (i = 0; i <= alunos.Length; i++)` o contador terminará a iteração em uma unidade além da capacidade do seu `array`, lembrando que em `C#` array começa no índice `0` e termina no índice `array.Length - 1`. Para corrigir basta fazer `for (i = 0; i < alunos.Length; i++)`.
- A média dos três alunos estão sendo armazenada no mesmo espaço de memória, a variável `média`. Para corrigir basta criar um vetor `media` com o mesmo tamanho de alunos, nesse caso três alunos três médias, `var media = new double[3];`.

O bug é o seguinte, se o usuário digitar uma nota que não seja um número o programa trava ou se o usuário digitar uma nota que não esteja entre `0` e `10` o programa se foge de seu escopo então para cada leitura de nota coloquei a seguinte verificação:

```
do{
    Console.Write($"Digite a enésima nota do aluno {i}: ");
    if (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out notaX)) notaX = -1;
} while((notaX < 0) || (notaX > 10));
```

Essa verificação usa o método [`Double.TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Double__) que tansforma uma string de um número no seu equivalente de ponto flutuante de precisão dupla e retorna um booleano indicando se a conversão foi bem-sucedida ou falhou. Caso o método falhe passa `-1` para a nota se houver sucesso passa a entrada convertida para nota e depois testa se a nota está no intervalo `0` e `10`. Estando no intervalo adequado passa para próxima ação não estando a nota faixa adequada é reiterada a pergunta sobre a nota.

```
using System;

namespace TesteRepeticao1
{
    class Program8
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var alunos = new int[3];
            var media = new double[3];
            int i, reprovados = 0, exame = 0, aprovados = 0;
            double nota1 = 0, nota2 = 0, nota3 = 0, mediaclasse = 0, somamedias = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < alunos.Length; i++)
            {
                do{
                   Console.Write($"Digite a primeira nota do aluno {i}: ");
                   if (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nota1)) nota1 = -1;
                } while((nota1 < 0) || (nota1 > 10));

                do{
                   Console.Write($"Digite a segunda nota do aluno {i}: ");
                   if (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nota2)) nota2 = -1;
                } while((nota2 < 0) || (nota2 > 10));

                do {
                   Console.Write($"Digite a terceira nota do aluno {i}: ");
                   if (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nota3)) nota3 = -1;
                } while((nota3 < 0) || (nota3 > 10));
                media[i] = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3;
                somamedias += media[i];
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            for (i = 0; i < alunos.Length; i++)
            {
                if(media[i] < 5)
                {
                    reprovados++;
                }
                else if ((media[i] >= 5) && (media[i] < 7))
                {
                    exame++;
                }
                else if ((media[i] >= 7) && (media[i] < 10))
                {
                    aprovados++;
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < alunos.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"A média do aluno {alunos[i]} é {media[i]}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            mediaclasse = somamedias / 3;
            Console.WriteLine($"O total de alunos reprovados é {reprovados}");
            Console.WriteLine($"O total de alunos em exame é {exame}");
            Console.WriteLine($"O total de alunos aprovados é {aprovados}");
            Console.WriteLine($"A média da classe é {mediaclasse}");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

[Código no Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LimeSubduedService)

Comment: Dentro do for na linha posso substituir os `do-whiles` por outros `for`?

Comment: @CarlosA. Acho que sim, desde que não seja nada extravagante.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a variável nota1, nota2 e nota3 como um array também

```
double[] notas = new double[3];
```

E fazer um "for" pra percorrer essas notas dentro do outro "for"

```
int i2;
for (i2 = 0; i2 < notas.Length; i2++)
{
    notas[i2] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi do seu código a variável `media` está sendo reescrita a cada laço de lançamento de notas dos alunos, portanto só permencerá nela o valor da média do último aluno cadastrado. Por isso a média de todos tem ficado igual e a situação é a mesma para os três.

Para resolver o problema, crie um vetor também para armezenar as médias.